# Why is my image rendering with an odd purple light? (trust me its not missing textures)

Tags: rendering

Im rendering a space station I modeled and for some reason only after rendering I get this weird purple light shining on everything. I call it a purple light because I DO NOT HAVE ANY MISSING TEXTURES. I tested this out by adding a simple mesh cube right in the frame of my image. Sure enough the side away from all of the lights on the space station turned purple. I have a feeling this is some odd rendering setting though I am not sure. Can anyone help?  [image]

Comment: Do you have enviroment texture? hard to say, but you could shate your blend file, with just the cube so some could take a look at it

Comment: Blender comes with an ambient environment light turned on by default.  Usually it's dark grey... I would check if it's somehow become purple for you.  It's in the world tab, as Surface

Comment: Hello :). If it happens *"only after rendering"* as you wrote, it might be something in the compositor.